# sliding panels in Loop, open all together

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, panel

I am trying to create for each member of my site a sliding panel where some infos are showed. I have no problem in showing the panels however when I click on one all of them open.
Its probably an error with the class tag as when they render they have the same class.
How can I give unique classes to the panel? Or I can I approach this issue?

My code is

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".flip").click(function(){
$(".panel").slideToggle("slow");
});
});'

'<?php if ( bp_has_members( "search_terms={$_POST['category']}")) : ?>
<?php while ( bp_members() ) : bp_the_member(); ?>

<div class="flip">Click to slide the panel down or up</div>
<div class="panel">Hello world!</div>

<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the jQuery `find` method for this. You'll want to wrap the two `div`s in a parent `div`, and then use the `parent` method from your clicked `flip` class.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".flip").click(function(){
        $(this).parent().find(".panel").slideToggle("slow");
    });
});'

'<?php if ( bp_has_members( "search_terms={$_POST['category']}")) : ?>
<?php while ( bp_members() ) : bp_the_member(); ?>

<div class="memberInfo">
    <div class="flip">Click to slide the panel down or up</div>
    <div class="panel">Hello world!</div>
</div>

<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

That will:

- Get the parent of the clicked `flip` element.
- Find a `panel` class inside it
- Perform `slideToggle` on it